# Error with USB WebCamera Mic

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, webcam, input

I have a USB web-cam which has an in-built microphone. It has no separate jack-like plug for microphone. And it's showing in the device-manager and it is the default microphone. When I get into its properties, the level of input is constantly at maximum level (CREAKING SOUND) and it is some random creaking voice. Please help me. In the web cam's manual , it says plug-to-play i.e no need of driver installation. And nothing is specified for download in there website. Here is an
[Amazon link](https://www.amazon.in/TVS-WC-103-HD-Webcam-1080Pixel/dp/B08G4X6TC1)

[image]

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look at the Microphone *Properties* and check the *Listen* and *Levels* tabs and [edit] your question with screenshots of these. From personal experience, these seem to be the most common sources of feedback or other audio problems (i.e. having the wrong playback device, Microphone volume or Microphone Boost settings).

Comment: @Anaksunaman i have set this as default and i don't know why the levels are  maximum always though not giving any input in sound recorder than a creaking sound at the begining.